# Background Service in apache cordova app

Tags: cordova, ios6, android-service, hybrid-mobile-app, background-service

I need to poll a server in a given interval with on a Apache Cordova app and notify the user if there is relevant information for him/her. I'm not sure if it could be done with webworkers because the event (server poll) also has to happen when the application is inactive in iOS and Android.

Has anyone faced a similar issue?, I've looked into [local noifications/dialogs](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-dialogs/blob/master/doc/index.md) to deliver the message, but I'm unsure of how to create the polling service.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6):

In my eyes permanent polling is never a good solution. I would advice you to use Push, so your server notifies the app as soon as there is new content available. It saves a lot of battery on your device, because it is only woken up if there really is an update. The Push Notification Services are built for exactly this purpose.

Have a look at the excellent [`Push Plugin` for Phonegap](https://github.com/phonegap-build/PushPlugin), which works for iOS, Android and even more platforms. For setting up the `Push Plugin` for iOS and Android you can read [Holly Schinsky's tutorial here](http://devgirl.org/2013/07/17/tutorial-implement-push-notifications-in-your-phonegap-application/).

In [Ray Wenderlich's tutorial here](http://www.raywenderlich.com/32960/apple-push-notification-services-in-ios-6-tutorial-part-1) you find information about how you could implement the server side described in great detail.

If you really want to stick with polling, I know there is the possibility to do so on iOS (see [this article](http://www.objc.io/issue-5/multitasking.html) about `Background Fetch`), not sure about Android (I guess you would need to implement a Service there). However, I never found a Phonegap plugin which handles background execution for both platforms accordingly.

Comment: +1 for Background Fetch. The battery drain is negligible for a simple task I think. I would not rush into a push notification solution as it brings extra server-sided logic with it and also you depend on a 3rd party (Apple servers in this case) to deliver your content...